# Is it ok to use mongo java driver version 3.2.2 to work with MongoDB 3.4

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

We are planing to migrate `mongoDB` from 3.2 to 3.4 but we do not want to use new features like decimal type and collation.

Is it ok to use `java` driver version 3.2 to work with `MongoDB` 3.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official [JAVA driver computability table](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility) it is not OK and you should be running version 3.4 of the driver.

Comment: Yes we can not use below 3.4 java driver version if we want to use new features of MongoDB 3.4 else we for existing features we can use < 3.4 java driver version. But we must have to make sure that MogoDB version must be installed with version 3.2.8 above